# Proof: $\forall \pi : V^\pi(s) = max_{a \in A_s} Q^\pi(s,a) \forall s \in S \Rightarrow \pi \text{ is optimal}$

Tags: machine-learning

This is a homework example for reinforcement (machine) learning that I have to solve. I just would like to know if my thoughts on this are somehow correct.

Let $\pi$ be a policy and $V^\pi(s)$ the value function to calculate a reward in any state $s$ under such a policy $\pi$.

Let us also define the partial ordering of policies. We write $\pi \geq \pi'$, meaning that policy $\pi$ is better or equal than another policy $\pi'$ if:

> $$V^\pi(s) \geq V^{\pi'}(s) \text{, for every state } s \in S$$

Further a policy $\pi^*$ is optimal if

> $$\pi^* \geq \pi \text{, }\forall \pi \Leftrightarrow V^{\pi^*}(s) = max_\pi V^\pi(s) \text{, } \forall s \in S$$

where

> $$V^{\pi^*}(s) = max_{a \in A_s}Q^{\pi^*}(s,a)$$

is the **Bellman optimality equation** for $V^{\pi^*}$ and $Q^{\pi^*}(s, a)$ being the *action value function* returning the value of an action $a \in A$ in a given state $s \in S$ under an optimal policy $\pi^*$.

My script also shows e.g. that there exists **at most** one function $V^{\pi^*}: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and then states a corollary:

> *Every policy $\pi$ for which $V^\pi$ satisfies the Bellman optimality equations
>   $$V^{\pi^*}(s) = max_{a \in A_s}Q^{\pi^*}(s,a)$$
>   is optimal*

and this is what I have to prove.

---

Imho it is clear that this corollary has to follow due to the definitions above. To say that such a $\pi$ is **not** optimal, despite it is satisfying the Bellman optimality equations breaks the definitions in my eyes.

That is why it is not clear to me what I have to prove here. I don't think that I have to prove this in a strict mathematical and/or formal way but I guess just saying that this breaks the definitions might not be enough.

So how could I prove this corollary? Please don't give full answers; hints should do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you requested we provide only hints:

1. Assume opposite
2. Write down what the opposite means (in a formal way)
3. Insert *Bellman optimality equation* into *formalized opposite*
4. Insert *Action-Value Function definition* into *formalized opposite*
5. Spot contradiction
6. q.e.d.?